# How to install Windows 11 having Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, windows, bios, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu 20.04 in an HP Spectre x360-13-ae052nr laptop. I have enabled booting from USB on BIOS configuration and I have tried to boot from the USB with Windows 11, but it does not boot from the USB and starts in Ubuntu 20.04.

I would like to know how I could install Windows 11 on my laptop having Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I don't want a dual boot. I want to switch from Ubuntu 20.04 to Windows 11.

Comment: Also worth reading: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/)

Comment: How you boot *external media* required to install an OS is very device specific; ie. you need to do whatever your device firmware requires. I have devices which require me to have device turned off, then I hold down a key & it'll start up & ask if I want to boot external media (to install OS), enter diags etc... Others require me to enter uEFI-Setup & select boot external on next boot, others to just press a key during boot...  All these will require you to write the windows ISO correctly to boot media as per microsoft documentation (*otherwise media will be ignored*)